# Posicionar elemento no meio da tela

Tags: css

Tentei ajustar um elemento (*sliders*) no meio da tela, mas não consegui fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meo objetivo é deixar esta imagem sempre ao centro, certinho, não importa o monitor que está sendo utilizado por outro usuário. Ou seja, a parte menor e maior deveriam ser da mesma altura, em todas as situações.

Segue o código que usei:

```
.img-responsive, .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel- 
inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%; 
height: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Uso a linguagem `R` junto com `Rmarkdown` para fazer isso.

- Quais propriedades resolveriam este problema?

Comment: Amigo explica ai, como que vc quer que não corte essa imagem, mas que ela ocupe a tela inteira? Vc quer que ela fique distorcida mesmo, tipo achatada https://prnt.sc/qx0jo1 e esse espaço vc já não verificou se existe algum tipo de margin ou padding nesse container que o slider está dentro?

Comment: Esquece a parte de "cortar". Como eu apenas ajustaria a figura ao centro? Desculpe, não entendo de `CSS` e eu apenas peguei este código do documento que foi gerado.

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso, mesmo com essa pergunta que você me mandou e com as respostas. Se tiver um tempo disponível, posso subir o arquivo e você pode acessá-lo do seu computador e ver melhor este código. Eu não entendo de CSS, e nem quero que você faça o trabalho por mim, mas é que talvez o problema nem esteja nesta parte do CSS, e eu não consigo identificar onde posso colocar o código.

Comment: Obs: Você colocou a altura maxima como 100%, ou seja, ele sempre vai entrar com 100% da tela, imagino que seja esse teu problema

Answer (score -1):

No contêiner pai que está o slide coloque a propriedade css margin: 0 auto!important; caso n resolver remova e ponha display:flex!important; justify-content: center!important;